# SUMS in Matrix report PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to build a matrix in a report. In the matrix I need to display sums on different levels, so to speak.

So I have a few rows in this order: account, task, user
Columns: DayBooked
Values: TotalTime and TotalTeamTime.
Slicers: User, Team, Account, Task, Date.

TotalTime is the a sum of hours booked on a given day. Let's pick one person X. For example he booked 8 hours in total today. The Person X is assigned to multiple teams, and his total booked time needs to be distributed to teams (TotalTeamTime) according to his allocation to teams (see the link).

What I also need to see is the TotalTime of all accounts per team on a given month, which comes from individual total bookings of team members and TotalTeamTime, coming from total bookings of members with certain percentage allocation to the team.

**The problem I am facing is duplicated values in the model for the TotalTime, which produces wrong sums in the report. There is also a screenshot included so that you see**

**Ultimately, what I need is the correct sums when I apply slicers in the report. I'm going to attach sample data.** Apologies for the possibly confusing explanation; the data model is pretty complex.

Here's the link to the xsl and pbi report sample data.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1YUwcu8rDAIs_UKgWFpBLzQwWL139okT7

and the screenshot is the formula I applied to solve the wrong sums problem. The calculation seems correct when I pick just one user, but the values are off on the team and other levels. [DAXFormula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqZ35.png)

Please let me know if I need to clarify the problem.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understood - is this what you are after?

```
MeasureTT = 
  SUMX(
    DISTINCT('FACT'[acct_user_period]),
    MAX ( 'FACT'[TotalTime (Hours)])
  )
```

Comment: hi Sam! not exactly.
1). Filter Ann on 28.01.2024 in the report for eg. That day she booked 8 hours in total. But because she's a member of 3 teams, the total hours get duplicated in the model, producing the wrong sum for her. (24). I solved this with the MeasureTotalTime.

2). Now Filter Tigers on 28.01.2024. for eg. MeasureTotalTime shows 8, but now I need 24 hours, because i want to see the total hours booked on the account from all individuals regardless of their assignment to teams. 

3) In the grand total i want to see how much people booked in total per account and all accounts

Comment: TotalTime (hours) = is hours logged per person per Account, regardless of team/task - yes? Try the above updated answer.

Comment: mmh it works in the sample data, but not in my real data model unfortunately. maybe you have suggestions as how to modify the measure with VARs in the screenshot i uplaoded?

Comment: Are the hours per person per account? Or per person per account per task? Ultimately I would suggest you clean up the data model so that you don't have duplicate hours. Usually one doesn't use the columns from the fact table as dimensions in visuals.

Comment: Per person, account, task. 
And Yeah, I know. the model is complex and annoying :D, but at the moment, I don't have a solution to modify it. Also, yes, I usually don't use the fields from fact tables for visuals, but there's no other way at the moment

Comment: So "Ann" on the "28/01/2024" did 16 hrs? https://i.stack.imgur.com/43R8T.png

Comment: 8. 
if you look at an account, i wanna see the total booked hours on this account on a given day. From all people regardless of team.

Comment: So it's per person per account (regardless of task). Ie the hours are duplicated per task. The answer above should work for you.